# Why a changed to a $scope field is not propagated to another field?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, typescript

I have a directive that accepts an array. It is initially undefined and then gets asynchronously defined at some point in time.

The directive looks similar to

```
function XYZDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            array: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', $scope => {
            $scope.$watch(() => $scope.array, (newValue, oldValue) => {
                $scope.firstElement =  (newValue && newValue.length > 0) 
                    ? newValue[0] 
                    : null;
            });

        }],

        templateUrl: URL
    };
}
```

This works fine. I wanted then to get rid fo the `$watch` and use simple binding.

```
function XYZDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            array: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', $scope => {

            $scope.getFirstElement = function() {
                return ($scope.array && $scope.array.length > 0) ? $scope.array[0] : null;
            }

            $scope.firstElement = $scope.getFirstElement();
        }],

        templateUrl: URL
    };
}
```

I would expect `$scope.firstElement` to get reevaluated every time  `$scope.array` changes.

This however does not work. If I add a watcher on `$scope.array` I can see it gets updated, but the change does not propagate to `$scope.firstElement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a statement, which is executed exactly once

```
$scope.firstElement = $scope.getFirstElement();
```

And then never again *(only if directive/controller is destroyed an rendered again)*

So, you should be observing the method

```
{{getFirstElement()}}
```

and that will really trigger this check again and again... and ... again.. so maybe `$watch` is better way to go *(e.g. watch until firstly array comes, and then remove watch)*